# Installing another version of motion on the pi

Tags: motion

Is it possible to install a second version of motion onto the pi and run both simultaneously. I have the normal one installed and working but I also need to be able to stream `rtsp` format which normal motion doesn't do and has to be built from source. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly have multiple instances of motion running. Could you just build the needed version from source and use it for all instances?